# Code if any 2 conditions are true over a set timeframe

Tags: sql

I am trying to determine the most efficient way to count the number of accounts who have purchased any 2 different products.  Product1, Product2, Product3, Product4, and Product5 are labeled as 1 if they have purchased the product and 0 if they have not. I am trying to limit the purchase_date to the previous month.  Not sure the best way to have the query check for multiple products across different dates.  First post here so apologies if I have left anything out!  Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT AccountID)
FROM Products
WHERE Purchase_Date > 2021-07-11
AND
```

Comment: Please, provide data. Table structure maybe? We need to find accounts, which bought 2 different products in 1 month, right?

Comment: Also tag with the database you areusing.

Comment: We need to know the table structure for Products in order to provide advice. The answer will vary if Products contains one row per product purchased, or if multiple product IDs can be specified on each row.

Comment: apologies and thanks for all the quick replies....so the table records the date and which products were purchased on that date by denoting a 1 or 0.  The accountID can only show up once per day, so if a purchase is made for product 1 and then later product2 there will only be one line.  I believe the answer given below has solved my problem. I will try and upload the data/table structure next time to avoid this.  Apologies again my first post here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have five columns and you want the number of rows that have exactly two "1"s in them, you can count up the matches:

```
select count(*)
from t
where (product1 + product2 + product3 + product4 + product5) = 2;
```